# function Return undefined array

Tags: javascript, html

This code gets the position of the mouse click related to the SVG,
in the console, it works fine, but when I tried to make additions to the HTML I got
Client.X error and it just send undefined, I do not know where is the error in the logic, I would appreciate any help I would get

[Screen shot to the error][1]

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
var Mok = document.getElementById('Monkeysss')
var values = alert_coords();
var first = Math.round(values[0]);
var second = Math.round(values[1]);
console.log(first);

function alert_coords(evt) {
  pt.x = evt.clientX;
  pt.y = evt.clientY;

  var cursorpt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  console.log(cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y);
  return [cursorpt.x, cursorpt.y]
}

function AddHtml(evt) {
  Mok.innerHTML += `${first},${second} `
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="Monkeysss">
    <P style="color: brown;">Values</P>
  </div>


  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 3056.000000 1504.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" , onclick="alert_coords(evt); AddHtml(evt)">
    
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

moved   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls8Se.png

Comment: You have two error the first one is `var values = alert_coords();` because function need a variable into `()` and second one you pass `evt` in the `onclick` function but i think you need `this`

Comment: What should i pass into the (),

Comment: Is ```onclick="alert_coords"``` instead of ```onclick="alert_coords(evt);"``` solving your problem?

Comment: No , it block the console from running as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did?

- Change `alert_coords(evt)` with `alert_coords(event)` because evt doesn't exist.
- Add the function `AddHtml` directly into `alert_coords` function
- Instead of return data from `alert_coords` active directly `AddHtml` with array coords

Now when you click will ouput coords.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var pt = svg.createSVGPoint();
var Mok = document.getElementById('Monkeysss');

function alert_coords(evt) {
  pt.x = evt.clientX;
  pt.y = evt.clientY;

  var cursorpt = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  console.log(cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y);
  
  AddHtml([cursorpt.x, cursorpt.y]);
}

function AddHtml(evt) {
  Mok.innerHTML += evt[0]+' '+evt[1]+'<br>';
}
```

```html
<div id="Monkeysss">
    <P style="color: brown;">Values</P>
  </div>


  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
  <svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600.000000pt" height="300.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 3056.000000 1504.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" , onclick="alert_coords(event);">
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: yeah that worked but for the sake of the argument why can`t i return an arrray from the function and use it else where
i made the code work 10 mins ago by removing the 2nd function and the return from the first
function and code be :              alert_coords(evt) {
    pt.x = evt.clientX;
    pt.y = evt.clientY;

    var cursorpt =  pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
    console.log(cursorpt.x + ", " + cursorpt.y );
    Mok.innerHTML += Math.round(cursorpt.x) + ", " + Math.round(cursorpt.y)+" "
  
}

Comment: You can use `Mok.innerHTML` directly into first function, you must alwys pass event click